# Bootstrap Navbar not working properly in mobile view after custom styling

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I fix spacing issues in bootstrap mobile view. My website runs perfectly on desktop but when I look at it in mobile view, there are spaces between the navbar menu links and the navbar itself. I used some margins in the desktop view so I think that's why it's doing it but how do I make it work for both?

Here is my html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Champs Haircuts</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav id="myNavBar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/logo.png" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="mainNavbar">
                <li><a href="services.html">Services & Pricing</a></li>
                <li id="contactLink"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="modal fade" id="callToActionModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!--Modal content -->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close">&times;</button>
                <h2 class="text-center modal-title">Champs Haircuts</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h2 class="text-center">Call 847-677-2768</h2>
                <p class="text-center">5113 Brown St, Skokie, IL 60077</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<header class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row row-header">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
                <h1>Welcome to<br> <span>Champs Haircuts.</span></h1>
                <br>
                <p>Look and Feel Like a Champion.</p>
                <br>
                <br>
                <button id="callToActionBtn" class="btn btn-lg">Make An Appointment</button>
                <div style="padding: 20px 20px"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/open-hours.png" alt="open hours" height="420" width="370">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

<div id="about">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="aboutDiv" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
                <h1 class="text-center">
                    Our Story
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div style="padding: 60px 60px"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                <p>Are you tired of feeling like just another number at your franchise haircut shop? Are you tired of
                    getting the same disappointing haircut? Have you learned to make peace with it because there
                    possibly can't be
                    anything better or maybe that you have reached your max looking good potential? Well if any of those
                    describe you and you want to change those experiences... Then look no further and enter Champs
                    Haircuts!
                    <br><br>
                    We have 15 years of experience providing excellent hairstyles, quality control, and top of the line
                    customer service. We are a small shop located in Skokie and we treat you, how you treat you. We
                    refuse to treat you like just another number. Champs Haircuts... Where you come to look and feel
                    like a champion.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <a href="https://plus.google.com/100864823698189828429/about?pid=6176986613869798882&oid=100864823698189828429" target="_new">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="images/champs-haircuts-lobby.jpg" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="testimonials">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="testimonialsHeaderDiv" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                <h1 class="text-center">
                    What People Say About Us On
                    <a class="underline_text" id="testimonialsYelp" href="http://www.yelp.com/biz/champs-haircuts-skokie">Yelp!</a>
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--
        Copyright (c) 2013 Bootsnipp.com

        Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated
        documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation
        the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and
        to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
        -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
                <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="quote-carousel">
                    <!-- Bottom Carousel Indicators -->
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#quote-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"><img class="img-responsive "
                                                                                                src="images/qazi.png"
                                                                                                alt="">
                        </li>
                        <li data-target="#quote-carousel" data-slide-to="1"><img class="img-responsive"
                                                                                 src="images/me.png"
                                                                                 alt="">
                        </li>
                        <li data-target="#quote-carousel" data-slide-to="2"><img class="img-responsive"
                                                                                 src="images/rand.png"
                                                                                 alt="">
                        </li>
                    </ol>

                    <!-- Carousel Slides / Quotes -->
                    <div class="carousel-inner text-center">

                        <!-- Quote 1 -->
                        <div class="item active">
                            <blockquote>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">

                                        <p>This place is great. Lidija offers exceptional customer service. She is
                                            extremely pleasant, gave me the best haircut I have ever received, and gives
                                            very flattering complements.

                                            Here are the services offered for the price of one haircut:
                                            1. Haircut
                                            2. Shampoo
                                            3. Face/Scalp Massage

                                            Oh my goodness the face massage is heaven. It feels so amazing. I sometimes
                                            want to go back just for the massage... And did I mention I received the
                                            best haircut ever?

                                            Sincerely,
                                            Qazi.
                                        </p>
                                        <small>Qazi</small>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </blockquote>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Quote 2 -->
                        <div class="item">
                            <blockquote>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">

                                        <p>All my life, I always went to the neighborhood salon where I received no
                                            haircut that I truly liked. There was always something wrong. Also, they
                                            treated me like a number. I was just another client they needed to get done
                                            with.

                                            I was recommended to try out Champs Haircuts by a good friend of mine who
                                            regularly went here for his haircuts. I was both nervous and excited at the
                                            same time.

                                            Now that I have had my first haircut here, I can confidently say that this
                                            is the best haircut place I have ever been to. The whole experience was just
                                            amazing. I never felt that good after getting a haircut. I guess It's
                                            because I had never received a proper haircut before this.

                                            I recommend everyone to try out Champs Haircuts. Just give it a try. Just
                                            one try. You will not regret it.</p>
                                        <small>Tenzin</small>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </blockquote>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Quote 3 -->
                        <div class="item">
                            <blockquote>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">

                                        <p>I initially found out about champ's haircuts by typing "best men's haircut
                                            near me" into a Google search. Based on the positive reviews I decided to
                                            give it a shot. I am extremely glad I did. It's been nearly 4 years since I
                                            started coming here and I have had a quality, professional haircut and
                                            service every time.

                                            Lidija takes her time and makes sure you are satisfied with your haircut
                                            before you leave. You also get a great scalp massage and hot steam towel as
                                            well. I recommend Lidija and champs haircuts to everyone looking for a long
                                            term hair stylist.</p>
                                        <small>Aida</small>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </blockquote>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="padding: 90px 90px">

                    </div>
                    <!-- Carousel Buttons Next/Prev -->
                    <a data-slide="prev" href="#quote-carousel" class="left carousel-control"><i
                            class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
                    <a data-slide="next" href="#quote-carousel" class="right carousel-control"><i
                            class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="callToActionDiv">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="text-center">
            <button id="callToActionBtnSecondary" class="btn btn-lg">Make An Appointment Now!</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <br>
        <hr>
        <div class="row row-content">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="services.html">Services & Pricing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <a href="https://plus.google.com/100864823698189828429/about" class="btn btn-circle" target="_new"><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-2x"></i></a>
                    <a href="http://www.yelp.com/biz/champs-haircuts-skokie" class="btn btn-circle" target="_new"><i
                            class="fa fa-yelp fa-2x"></i></a>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my css:

```
html, body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
    padding-top: 100px;
}

#myNavBar {
    background-color: #006495;
    height: 100px;
}

#myNavBar a {
    color: white;
    height: 100px;
}

.navbar-brand {
    font-size: 2em;
    line-height: 70px;
}

#mainNavbar > li {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    margin-left: 20px;
    background-color: #004C70;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

#mainNavbar > li:hover {
    background-color: #0093D1;
}

#mainNavbar > #contactLink {
    background-color: #F4D00C;
    color: black;
}

#myNavBar span {
    background: white;
}

#mainNavbar > #contactLink:hover {
  animation: shake 0.82s cubic-bezier(.36,.07,.19,.97) both;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

@keyframes shake {
  10%, 90% {
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }

  20%, 80% {
    transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
  }

  30%, 50%, 70% {
    transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  }

  40%, 60% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }
}

.navbar-nav > #contactLink > a {
    color: #004C70;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.jumbotron h1 > span{
    color: #006495;
}

#callToActionBtn:hover {
    background: #006495;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#callToActionBtn {
    font-weight: bold;
    background: white;
    color: #3d3d3d;
    border: 2px solid #3d3d3d;
}

#aboutDiv {
}

#about h1 {
    background: #004C70;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px 20px;
}

#about p {
    font-size: 1.4em;
    font-style: normal !important;
    color: #666666;
}

/* Carousel */

#quote-carousel {
    padding: 0 10px 30px 10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    /* Control buttons  */
    /* Previous button  */
    /* Next button  */
    /* Changes the position of the indicators */
    /* Changes the color of the indicators */
}
#quote-carousel .carousel-control {
    background: none;
    color: #CACACA;
    font-size: 2.3em;
    text-shadow: none;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
#quote-carousel .carousel-control.left {
    left: -60px;
}
#quote-carousel .carousel-control.right {
    right: -60px;
}
#quote-carousel .carousel-indicators {
    right: 50%;
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin-right: -19px;
}
#quote-carousel .carousel-indicators li {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 4px solid #CCC;
    border-radius: 50px;
    opacity: 0.4;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.4s;
}
#quote-carousel .carousel-indicators .active {
    background: #333333;
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    border-color: #f33;
    opacity: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.carousel-inner {
    min-height: 300px;
}
.item blockquote {
    border-left: none;
    margin: 0;
}
.item blockquote p:before {
    content: "\f10d";
    font-family: 'Fontawesome';
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#testimonialsHeaderDiv {
    height: 100px;
    transform: skew(-20deg);
}

#testimonials h1 {
    background: #004C70;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px 20px;
}

#testimonials h1 a {
    color: #F2635F;
}

#testimonials h1 a:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.underline_text {
      border-bottom: solid 2px #F2635F;
      display: inline;
      padding-bottom: 3px;
}

#calltoactiondiv {
    background: #eeeeee;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    color: #333333;
}

#callToActionBtnSecondary:hover {
    background: #006495;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#callToActionBtnSecondary {
    font-weight: bold;
    background: white;
    color: #3d3d3d;
    border: 2px solid #3d3d3d;
    padding: 20px 35px;
}


footer .navbar-nav li{
    margin-right: 20px;
}

#servicesHeader {
    background: #006495;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px 10px;
}

/* Contact Page Styles */
#contactHeader {
    background: #006495;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px 10px;
}

.form-horizontal input {
    font-size: 1.7em;
    height: 50px;
}

.form-horizontal input {
    outline: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(198, 198, 198);
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-left: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.form-horizontal input:focus {
    border-bottom: solid 4px #F2635F;
}

.form-horizontal textarea {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(198, 198, 198);
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-left: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.form-horizontal textarea:focus {
    border-bottom: solid 4px #F2635F;
}

/*
.form-horizontal p {
    color: rgb(93, 107, 125);
    font-size: 1.4em;
}
*/
#contactDescription {
    color: rgb(93, 107, 125);
    font-size: 1.4em;
}
.form-horizontal button {
    background: #006495;
    color: #eeeeee;
}

.form-horizontal button:hover {
    background: #F2635F;
    color: #F4D00C;
}

.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: rgb(93, 107, 125); }
.form-control:-moz-placeholder { color: rgb(93, 107, 125);}
.form-control::-moz-placeholder { color: rgb(93, 107, 125); }
.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder { color: rgb(93, 107, 125); }

/* Services and Pricing */
.services h2 {
    color: #636466;
}

.price {
    color: #636466;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.serviceDescription {
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
```

I tried looking it up on stackoverflow and other resources, but nothing matched my exact scenario. I also tried to use media queries for screen size less than 480px. It still doesn't work. Thanks in advance for the help.

Here is a link to the site [developertenzin.github.io/champs_haircuts](http://developertenzin.github.io/champs_haircuts)

Comment: which problem that your getting?

Comment: @sagarkodte The navbar is not working properly in mobile collapsed view. I just added a link to the current state of the website.

Comment: you want to add background to collapse menu?

Comment: It's working when i click. It's collapsing. I'm not getting what you want to change.:(

Comment: Oh I'm sorry for the misunderstanding. I am referring to the little spaces I get when it is in mobile view. Try clicking on the toggle button, and you will what I am talking about.

Answer (score 2):

```
    Please add this in your custome css file 


    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #myNavBar {background-color: #006495;height: auto;padding: 12px 0px;}
    .navbar-header{ height: 74px;}
    #myNavBar a{height:auto;}
    .navbar-nav {margin: 0px auto !important;}
    #mainNavbar > li {margin-left: 0px;border-radius: 4px;margin-top:7px;}
    #callToActionBtnSecondary{padding: 10px;}
    #calltoactiondiv{padding:10px;}
    #testimonials h1{padding: 0px;margin: 0px auto;}
   .jumbotron{padding-top:0px !important;}
    }
```

Comment: It didn't work. It corrected the spacing but now the link elements are all squeezed in to the right.

Answer (score 0):

in your css remove margin from #mainNavbar > li

and add your margin

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
#mainNavbar > li {
   margin-left: 20px;
   border-radius: 4px;
}
}
```